# Error starting weblogic in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, weblogic11g

When I start a Weblogic Server 11gR1 (10.3.1) in the server tab in Eclipse (3.4.2) I *immediately* get an error popup: Starting ... has encounterd a problem. Server ... failed to start. 
However the starting continues and the server ends up in RUNNING mode after some 8 seconds.
No ears deployed, fresh domain and/or server instance.
It used to work fine and I didn't change any configuration as far as I am aware.
Any ideas?

A new server runtime makes no difference. But when I start the server in debug mode, there is no error popup.
When I start the server normally the error pops up and the server starts in debugging state. Remarkable, because while creating the server runtime I did *not* check the box "always start Weblogic Server in debug mode".

A new workspace and new server runtime solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your Server Runtime is corrupted. Try to drop it and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, try adding a -clean option to your eclipse startup.